# Node.js TCP server on Heroku/AppFog

Tags: c++, c, node.js, heroku, appfog

Here is my code for a node.js TCP server hosted on both Heroku and AppFog. My client was written in C and it simply sends a message to the server and get the response. When I host the server on local, they work fine. But when I try to connect to the online server, the client fails("ERROR connecting: Operation timed out"). Any idea what happened?

Server(node.js):

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.on("data", function(data){
    socket.write(data.toString());
  });
});

var port = process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 8081;
console.log(port);
server.listen(port);
```

Client(C, from http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");
    while (1){
    printf("Please enter the message: ");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
    n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    }
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I ran your code on my local machine and it worked. Time out indicates that your server is not reachable. Check if you are using correct address and access is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The client must always connect on port **80** regardless of what `process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT` is set to. AppFog proxies requests from port 80 to the port your app is running on.

Comment: I changed my request to port 80 and it did connect to the server this time. But the server still could not get any data.